# Action Editor moves multiple tagged objects?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

Hello once again Stack Exchange;
Today i'm facing the trouble of animation without the use of the timeline, and onto the usage of Dope Sheets and the Action Editor.

My Question is how do I individually animate single objects in one Action? Each time I try to insert a key frame for one object in the next frame, the other object within the action follows that exact location? I'm probably being a plank, but i'l get my head round it somehow...

Here's some image sources of what I mean:

In Frame 1 of Action:
[image: Source 1 - Frame action 1]
[image: Source 1 - Frame action 2]

Hope I hear from you soon Stack Exchange users <3

Comment: This answer may be of help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/is-it-possible-to-use-one-action-for-multiple-objects

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use bones? For what purpose should this animation / action be? For Blender Render / Blender Game / exported for other programs? As far as i know, the actions are bound to an armature object. You wwould eed to create bones through your player and animate them.

Comment: Using skeletal animation is quite a good idea indeed. Check out [the Character Animation](https://cloud.blender.org/p/character-animation/) course on Blender Cloud for some good training!

Answer (score 0):

It is my second day using Blender so I am positive some of the following terminology is wrong.

I ran into this exact same issue. I don't quite understand why, but I think the caveat is that Blender does not let you have a single "Action" do different things to more than a single "Blender Object".

In the *Action Editor*, when you use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> to select two meshes and key <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe, it links the two Blender Objects to that Action - which is a single transform. This moves the secondary Blender Object inside of the primary Blender Object since they now have the same transform.

What I believe Blender wants you to do is instead create this Blender Object called a "Pose?", which is a hierarchy tree of *Armature Bones*. Your bones get attached to the mesh through parenting and then moving the bones in *Pose Mode* will move the mesh.

The pose is now the thing that you move around to create the desired animation. You enter a special *Pose Mode* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to interact with the bones. Lastly there is a special *Pose Tools* section in this panel called the *Toolshelf* (w/ mouse in *3D Viewport*, key <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle open/close). In the *Pose Tools* section, you will see *Keyframes: Insert | Remove*, and this time around the *Action Editor* will save and display all the different transforms for the armature.

You can find a few sample rigs online which showcase the relationship between the armatures and meshes. I will give the disclaimer that I know next to nothing about modeling, and I am sure I have botched some of this explanation.

Comment: The action contains information like "Set the location to `(1, 2, 3)`". Anything that you attach this action to will simply follow that information.