# Is it possible to use one action for multiple objects?

Tags: animation

Just as the title says,
imagine you are building a glass sliding door,but you need to move both parts in the oppsite direction, but that creates 2 actions, is it possible to fuse these two into one?
To be neater.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using armature for this may be a good solution.

- ### CREATING AN ACTION FROM SCRATCH

  Add an *Armature*-->*Single Bone*, duplicate it in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and place each bone on each separate object. Select the first object, then the second one and finally the Armature in *Object Mode*, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*With Automatic Weights*.
  [image]

Keyframe the movement for each bone and make an action of it in *NLA Editor*. You now have one action for two separated objects.
[image]

- ### USING THE EXISTING ACTIONS

In this case I've got three objects with three different animations/actions. I'll merge these into one single action using an armature.
[image]
[image]

Add Armature-->*Single Bone* and snap it to the origin point of the first object. Snap the cursor to the second object in *Object Mode* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*), then select the bone, enter *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. It'll snap next bone to the second object. Repeat the same process with the third one as pictured below. Rotate all the bones in *Edit Mode* by 90 degress so they all stay horizontal.
[image]

In *Pose Mode* select the bone, go to the *Bone Constraints* header and give it a ***Copy Transforms*** constraint. Set the bones targets to the coresponding objects as pictured below. Now the bones are following the objects' animations.
[image]

Select all bones in *Pose Mode* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>), then go to *Object Mode*-->*Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>)-->*Animation*-->***Bake Animation***. Check all the checkboxes in a window there, and set the *Bake Data* type to ***Pose***. After clicking *OK* the new action in a *NLA Editor*'ll appear.
[image]
[image]

Now you have the copied movement of the objects baked into the keyframes of the armature, so you don't need the objects' animations anymore. Delete each one in a *Dope Sheet Editor*.
[image]

Finally being in *Object Mode* select all the objects, then the armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Set Parent*-->*With Automatic Weights*. Push down an action in *NLA Editor* to create an action block on a strip.
[image]

Comment: For some reason it doesnt work for me?
https://giphy.com/gifs/xUPGcySH21Hxjpugfu/fullscreen

Comment: That's because you've added two separate armatures. You have to create just one. Add the second bone with Shift+A being in armature's *edit mode*, not *object mode*. I've updated the first .gif to make it clearer.

Comment: too bad u cant add armatures to cameras

Comment: @Yeets You can probably mitigate that with a constraint tied to a bone. Not that I've tried it, but it's how I would go about doing it.

Failing that, you could also probably use a basic driver.