# How to bake animation in blender 2.8?

Tags: animation, export, baking, nla-editor, actions

I'm only starting on blender with the 2.8 version

I want to do several animations by moving the different donuts up and down so I started animating with actions. But I got one action per object and I would like to merge/bake them all, so I can start anew and do a completly different animation with the same objects.

Plus I intend to import everything on unity and for now I can only play one action each at the time :(

I watched a few tutorial on youtube were you could bake NLA actions in the older blenders versions.

thank you for your time,

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I do recomend you to stay on blender 2.79 version... i dont know why people are jumping to 2.80 as it is a beta version. if you are working seriously onm your project, you should stay in the full version before jump to 2.8 I myself realised some bugs in the new version and i wont risk my projects. Wait for the full release version

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/is-it-possible-to-use-one-action-for-multiple-objects/194841#194841 This works

Answer (score 16):

You can bake animation in Blender 2.8!

You'll need access to the Object pill menu. The easiest way to get to this is by clicking on the Animation workspace tab. Then, inside the right layout panel it opens click Object -> Animation -> Bake Action

There you will have access to all the required settings for baking.

**Note:** If you are animating poses, you can also get to the menu from the equivalent Pose pill menu. Pose -> Animation -> Bake Action

On the menu it pulls up, you can also choose whether you'd like to bake poses, or object data.

[image: Bake Action menu item location]

Comment: This comment needs visuals. Everything in blender has a header and I am not seeing object tab.