# How to export multiple combined animations in a single glTF file

Tags: animation, nla-editor, gltf

**TL;DR:** I can't find a reliable way to export in a single glTF file multiple "composed" animation, i.e. themself composed of several animations.

I created, via the Action Editor multiple animations `Walki` (to walk), `Hello` (to wave the hand) and `Hat` (to move the head). I manage to export in glTF (`.glb`) all these animations by "staching" them (in Action Editor, click on "stach") with the armature selected, and I also managed to combine them by giving them the same NLA track name:

[image]

But now when I export into glTF 2.0 (using "Group by NLA Track"), the final result I get when I open the `.glb` file in Godot (a game engine) is very far from what I'd expect from Blender, in many aspects:

- **Missing animations**: only two animation tracks are exported while I'd expect to see 4 animations:

  [image]
- **Bad length**: for instance the `HatHello` animation is supposed to last 81 frames/3.37 seconds. In Godot, even after making sure the import is done at 24 FPS, the animation is made of 17 frames (IPS mode)/1.6 seconds:

  [image]
- **Not playing at all the good animation**: Then, when I play them in Godot, they are often completely unrelated with the original animation. For instance, HatHello is supposed to be only a head move + a hand wave (and this is confirmed when I play the animation in blender by unchecking all tracks but the two `HatHello` ones)... and I actually see a different thing: it actually combine a walk and a head move, moves the head in the wrong direction, and never wave the hand! Similarly, the SlowMove-loop one is not the expected one: I scaled the up walk to have a very long walk, and I scaled down the waving to have a very short hand wave in the middle: the exported file basically plays both at normal speed at the same time. Even worse: if I need to mute a channel to work on a single animation, then the final animation will be different.

Any idea what I made wrong?

[image]

Comment: The glTF exporter is bad with animations. Stick to 1 action = 1 glTF animation and use the NLA editor *only* to stash the actions (and even that has problems).

Comment: @scurest Thanks for your comment. This is quite sad, it means there is no appropriate way to setup a more complex animation? (I'm also thinking that NLA/VSE should be rewritten to allow more complex scenarios: for instance I don't think it's possible in NLA to define a new action from previous actions and reuse it later on)

Comment: I found the bug report here https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/763

Comment: Also, there is a super dirty work-around: it's possible to bake actions by checking only the box of the tracks to play, then bake actions using https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137483/how-to-bake-animation-in-blender-2-8 (make sure however to check the "Bake Data: pose" if you are baking an armature), stash the new action, then removing temporarily all tracks that are not the stashed ones and exporting. Then undo the removing not to lose the original NLA tracks... But it's very dirty, and the baking won't update when changing the original NLA tracks.