# Importing FBX causes all scene animations to become slower

Tags: animation, import, keyframes, .fbx, scene

I have a scene with animations, but when I import any fbx it changes something with the animations that makes them play slower; so I cannot import anything unless I want to reanimate the entire scene. The place on the timeline does not change, nor the keyframes, nor playback scale. I've tried restarting Blender, unchecking options at import screen, being in different modes, having different things selected, importing into different collections; I cannot think of what might be causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, decided to undo/redo the import and look around to see what changed, and I noticed the sequencer time changing. Took awhile till I looked at the FPS and that is what changed, apparently the FBX's FPS was 24 and my project was 30, so every time I imported it changed the FPS. It never occurred to me that importing an FBX would change the projects FPS, glad I know now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

The (Probable) reason this is happening is that the FBX file is just a big file. One way you can tell is by looking at the amount of FPS that is playing. You can see it here:

[image]

When the text is red, that means that blender is taking a long time to calculate the animation. The main reason this is happening is that your PC is not very good (Or the FBX animation is just a high quality animation that takes blender a long time to preview). There isn't really a good fix besides upgrading your PC but to make it play faster, you could get a lower quality version of the FBX or try [Baking the Animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137483/how-to-bake-animation-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Thanks for your response, at first I thought it was the fps, but I did some testing and fps does not drop when in non material mode, but animation does slow down. Doesn't seem to be an fps/pc issue, it seems that importing any fbx slows my animation down on the timeline. There is no numerical change or keyframe position change, so what is causing the slow down I do not know.

Comment: Do you think you could share the FBX and .Blend files?

Comment: To add to above comment. Use https://pasteall.org/blend/ 